# Push and pass array parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a little recursion routine, and just curious how to push an array item and pass the array item in the call to recurse?  Like this:

```
function recurseFunc(element) {
    var $ = window.jQuery;
    var walkFunc = function(element, apattern) {
        if($(element).parents('[pattern]')[0]) {
            return walkFunc($(element).parents('[pattern]')[0], apattern.push($(element).attr('pattern')));
        }
        return concat(apattern,$(element).attr('pattern'));      
    }

    return walkFunc(element,[]);
}
```

Array.push returns the count of the Array and not the Array object.

Comment: So you need a `var list = ...` on one line and pass it in as another. Is this a big deal?

Comment: Uhhh, don't do it in one line as it isn't designed for chaining.

Comment: Your recursive function would have to take an array as well.

Comment: You _could_ do `walkFunc($(element).parents('[pattern]')[0], apattern.concat([$(element).attr("pattern")]))`

Comment: Thats it @soktinpk perfect!  You should move this out to the actual answer.